# Flutter: type 'Future<bool>' is not a subtype of type 'bool' in type cast

Tags: android, flutter, dart, dart-async

I'm trying to display a widget based on the value returned. But getting the below error.

```
type 'Future<bool>' is not a subtype of type 'bool' in type cast
```

Here is the source code which is causing the error:

```
  Future<bool> fetchCourses() async {
    List courses = [];
    final loggedInUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    if (loggedInUser != null) {
      final userCollection = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(loggedInUser.uid).get();
      courses = userCollection.get('coursesEnrolled');
    }
    if (courses.length == 0) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
.
.
.
bool hasCourses = fetchCourses() as bool;
.
.
.
hasCourses ? ListAllUserEnrolledCourses() : Container(),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fetchCourses()` returns a `Future<bool>`, use `FutureBuilder` to resolve the `Future`.

```dart
FutureBuilder<bool>(
  future: fetchCourses(),
  builder: (_, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return snapshot.data ? ListAllUserEnrolledCourses() : Container();
    }
    return Text('Loading...');
  },
),
```

Answer (score 2):

```
bool hasCourses = await fetchCourses();
```

You need to await for it to finish, but no need to cast it.